# Getting an n-size vector of digits-only from a numeric value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function which returns a **vector of numerics** representing n decimal digits of the provided x numeric. And this is the code I wrote so far:

```
decdig <- function(x, n){
   stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
   stopifnot(is.integer(n))
   head ( lapply(strsplit( as.character(x) , ""), as.numeric) , n)
}
```

**So the instruction:**

> decdig(pi, 10L)

Returns:

```
[[1]]
 [1]  3 NA  1  4  1  5  9  2  6  5  3  5  8  9  7  9
```

**But it should be:**

```
3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3
```

Which means it should produce a **numeric vector** without rounding.

I have a problem with getting rid of the NA values sitting there due to a comma. I'm trying to make it as elegant as possible, without use of control-flow mechanisms.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You could stick a `gsub('\\D', '', as.character(x))` in there.

Comment: @jbaums Yes, it helped with the NA. Now, I am trying to represent the result as numeric vector of n size, there are some problems with it.

Comment: What do you want to do with negative values? Do you want to retain the minus sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
decdig <- function(x, n) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
  stopifnot(is.integer(n))
  z <- sub('\\D', '', 
           sprintf(paste0('%.', n - nchar(abs(floor(x))) + 2, 'f'), x))
  head((strsplit(z, '')[[1]]), n)
}

decdig(pi, 10L)
# [1] 3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5 3
```

We calculate the number of decimal places needed (if any) by subtracting the number of leading digits from `n`, then pass this to `sprtinf` to coerce `x` to character with that number of decimal places. Then we sub out non-digit characters (which should only include `,` or `.`, depending on locale). Then we split at each character and coerce to `numeric`.